# Azure App Service: Converting Staging Slot into Standalone App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, staging, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure App with a Staging Slot. I'm trying to find a way to convert my Staging Slot into a normal Standalone App

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Why do I want to do this?**

Because I want to scale down my app from `S1->B1`

Since `B1` doesn't **support the deployment slots** now I'm completely blocked from scaling down my App without deleting and recreating it.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you just creating a new app and deploying it again there?

Comment: @juunas I've provided the enough details in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert a deployment slot to a new standalone Web App.  You need to create a new Web App and redeploy your code.

Comment: thanks for your response, do you have any link to provide to make sure it couldn't able to convert? Also, I've updated my question do you know any workaround for my issue ?

Comment: Just delete the deployment slots before scaling down.